# Continuity of increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f$ is an increasing function over the reals, given a number $M$, is it always possible to find some $x \ge M$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x$? This seems like it should be intuitively true but I can't find a proof.

Comment: I believe the argument [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56831) should work for this problem.

Comment: Yes, it’s true, because [a monotone function on any subset of $\Bbb R$ has only countably many points of discontinuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404071/does-a-monotone-function-on-an-arbitrary-subset-of-mathbb-r-always-have-at-mo).

Answer (score 1):

The following result is well known.
Suppose $f$ is a real valued function monotone in the interval $[a, b], a < b$. Then $f$ can have at most only a countable number of discontinuity in $[a,b]$.  Hence there are uncountably many number of points in $[a, b]$ at which  $f$  is continuous.

Apply this result to an increasing function.
For your question $f$ is increasing in the real numbers.  So given any $M$, take the interval, say $[M, M+1]$.  Then the restriction of $f$ to $[M, M+1]$ is monotone. Hence there are infinite number of points in $(M, M+1)$ at which $f$  is continuous.  Of course there is an $x$ in $(M, M+1)$ ( so $x > M$) at which $f$ is continuous.

More general, if $f$ is a monotone function on the real numbers **R**, then $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on **R**, i.e., except for a subset $E$ of measure $0$, $f$ is continuous. So given $M$ , there are numbers > $M$ and numbers < $M$ and arbitrary close to $M$ at which $f$ is continuous.

For a reference to the result stated above see Theorem 3 in my article [Monotone Function, Function of Bounded Variation, Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Mono_bound/mono.htm)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is affirmative. Let M>0 be given. Then f is bounded and integrable over [M,2M], being monotone. Then f is continuous almost everywhere in [M,2M] by Lebesgue's theorem. So there x>M where f is continuos.